# Combining arrays from config files

Tags: php, arrays

Having a hard time combining these arrays.

I want to be able to load multiple configuration files and build one big array to be able to call anywhere in my application.

test_config1.php

```
$config1=array();
$config1['Key1']['AnotherKey1']='Value 1';
$config1['Key2']['AnotherKey1']='Value 2';
$config1['Key3']['AnotherKey1']='Value 3';

return $config1;
```

test_config2.php

```
$config2=array();
$config2['Different Key 1']='Different Value 1';
$config2['Different Key 2']='Different Value 2';
$config2['Different Key 3']='Different Value 3';
$config2['Key3']['AnotherKey1']['test']='Test 1';

return $config2;
```

Configure class:

```
class Configure
{
    public static $configArray = array();

    public static function loadConfig($configSource)
    {
        # Explicitly turn this into an array.
        $configSource=(array)$configSource;

        # Loop through the array.
        foreach($configSource as $configFileName)
        {
            $config=require_once $configFileName;

            self::$configArray[]=$config;
            unset($config);
        }

        return self::$configArray;
    }
}

print_r(Configure::loadConfig(array('test_config1.php', 'test_config2.php')));

//print_r(Configure::loadConfig('test_config1.php'));
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Key1] => Array
                (
                    [AnotherKey1] => Value 1
                )

            [Key2] => Array
                (
                    [AnotherKey1] => Value 2
                )

            [Key3] => Array
                (
                    [AnotherKey1] => Value 3
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Different Key 1] => Different Value 1
            [Different Key 2] => Different Value 2
            [Different Key 3] => Different Value 3
            [Key3] => Array
                (
                    [AnotherKey1] => Array
                        (
                            [test] => Test 1
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

**Wanted:**

```
Array
(
    [Key1] => Array
        (
            [AnotherKey1] => Value 1
        )

    [Key2] => Array
        (
            [AnotherKey1] => Value 2
        )

    [Key3] => Array
        (
            [AnotherKey1] => Value 3
            [AnotherKey2] => Array
                (
                    [test] => Test 1
                )
        )


    [Different Key 1] => Different Value 1
    [Different Key 2] => Different Value 2
    [Different Key 3] => Different Value 3
)
```

I have tried `self::$configArray=array_merge(self::$configArray, $config);` which gives:

```
[Key3] => Array
    (
        [AnotherKey2] => Array
            (
                [test] => Test 1
            )

    )
```

And `self::$configArray=self::$configArray + $config;` which leaves out `$config2['Key3']['AnotherKey2']['test']='Test 1';` from the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code (not tested):

```
class Configure
{
public static $configArray = array();

public static function loadConfig($configSource)
{
    # Explicitly turn this into an array.
    $configSource=(array)$configSource;

    # Loop through the array.
    foreach($configSource as $configFileName)
    {
        $config=require_once $configFileName;

        if (empty(self::$configArray)) {
            self::$configArray = $config;
        } else {
            foreach ($config as $key => $value) {
                self::$configArray[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
        unset($config);
    }

    return self::$configArray;
}
}
```

Update for multiple similar keys:

```
class Configure
{
public static $configArray = array();

public static function loadConfig($configSource)
{
    # Explicitly turn this into an array.
    $configSource=(array)$configSource;

    # Loop through the array.
    foreach($configSource as $configFileName)
    {
        $config=require_once $configFileName;

        if (empty(self::$configArray)) {
            self::$configArray = $config;
        } else {
            self::$configArray = array_merge_recursive(self::$configArray, $config);
        }
        unset($config);
    }
    return self::$configArray;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that does the same thing as `array_merge()`

Comment: Now I've saw that you have multiple similar keys... Well I've updated my answer.

Comment: Ah, `array_merge_recursive()`, right on. Never used that function before. Works.

Comment: Only problem is that I can't use both the `Configure::loadConfig()` calls at the same time. Gives an error: "Warning: array_merge_recursive(): Argument #2 is not an array". `$config=require_once $configFileName;` returns `boolean true` during the second call.

Comment: Either you cast it to array or you check if it's an array, if not you're adding the value to a freshly created array to pass it as second argument. If you're calling loadConfig multiple times, why it's static?